# matlab design the uipanel

Tags: matlab, position, uicontrol

I want to show the image (path of file) and below to put the cells.

Unfortunately, the image disappeared.
this is the GUI with the image. I want the yellow cell will be below the image.
[image]

this is the gui after my change:
[image]

```
hFig = figure('Name','Step 3 of 4: Choose data for each image','Menubar','none', 'Resize','off', ...
    'WindowStyle','modal', 'Position',[300 300 1150 500]);
set(gcf,'NumberTitle','off')
movegui(hFig, 'center');



%# top/bottom panels
S.fh = uipanel('Parent',hFig, 'BorderType','none', ...
    'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0.002 1 0.28]);

Layout = GridLayout(S.fh, ...
'NumRows', 2, ...
'NumCols', 3, ...
'HGap', 10, ...
'VGap', 5, ...
'Margin', 10, ...
'CellMargin', 10, ...
'CellColor', 'y');


for RIdx = 1:Layout.NumRows
    for CIdx = 1:Layout.NumCols

        if (RIdx == 1)
           UIArgs = {'Style','text', 'String',choice{CIdx}};
        else
           UIArgs = {'Style','edit', 'String',''};
        end

        hFig = Layout.Cell(RIdx,CIdx);
        uicontrol(hFig, UIArgs{:});
    end
end


S.pb = uicontrol('style','pushbutton',...
             'units','pix',...
            'position',[380 20 180 30],...
            'string','Submit',...
            'callback',{@pb_call});


S.pc = uicontrol('style','pushbutton',...
             'units','pix',...
            'position',[580 20 180 30],...
            'string','change the image',...
            'callback',{@pc_call});

Update(Layout);
```

Comment: Thou shalt not name your variables like builtin matlab functions! (I am referring to `sum`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not really *have to* program it yourself, there is the [GridLayout FEX contribution](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29472):

> GridLayout was inspired by the GridBagLayout manager. It is equally flexible but more intuitive for my taste and it also requires less boilerplate code.

It will definitely ease your programing work..

Comment: thank you but I got an error when I typed:

GridLayoutDemo1
??? Undefined function or method 'GridLayout' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in ==> GridLayoutDemo1 at 13
Layout = GridLayout(Parent, ...

Comment: @AlonShmiel you need to add the path to the .m files to matlab path. To do that, cd to the directory where you unziped GridLayout and type `addpath(pwd)`. Then cd to Demo and run the examples.

Comment: thank you! I succeeded to see the examples. now I am trying to do something like this in my project. I will update this topic later. thank you!

Comment: @AlonShmiel You simply copied the example without trying to adapt it to your needs. I will not solve your programing problems for you. I am sure I helped you enough - try to understand first how the GridLayout works before writing the code. You can do it :)

Comment: ok, I tried and am trying.. I will update my topic later if I won't succeed.. thank you for help :)

Comment: @AlonShmiel Good! don't give up so quickly ;)